# C# Generic conditional where clause

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to know if it is possible to introduce conditional within where clause. For example if I have the two generics:

```
    public static Y Convert<T, Y>(T itemToConvert)
        where T : IDataTypeConverter, new()
        where Y : IDataTypeConverter2, new()
    {
    }

    public static Y Convert2<T, Y>(T itemToConvert)
        where T : IDataTypeConverter2, new()
        where Y : IDataTypeConverter, new()
    {
    }
```

How to join them into only one?

Thanks!

Comment: So do you want to restrict the type of the instance to be converted to not be the same as the type of the returned instance?  Or do you just want to allow either type for each paramter?

Comment: Depend on the situation I call Convert or Convert2, the only difference between this two is the order the parameters are passed, two scenarios, first one (IDataTypeConverter, IDataTypeConverter2) and second one (IDataTypeConverter2,IDataTypeConverter) so depends on the order of the parameters Y takes and returns IDataTypeConverter(second scenario) or IDataTypeConverter2 (first scenario).

Comment: Based on what you said I think both @renan and kevin have answered your question correctly.  They do not restrict either of your paramters to IDataTypeConverter nor IDataTypeConverter2.  Therefore, you can pass in <IDataTypeConverter, IDataTypeConverter2> or <IDataTypeConverter2, IDataTypeConverter>.  However, this unfortunately also allows you to pass in <IDataTypeConverter, IDataTypeConverter> or <IDataTypeConverterTwo, IDataTypeConverterTwo> which you seem to not care about. You can throw a runtime error if you do care about restricting the user from passing in the same generic parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Make both data type converters inherit from the same interface. Then use that interface in the where clause.

Comment: I think you refer to what kevin refers in the below example, but this does not work because as steaks says below in his comment, the type of the instance to be converted cannot be the same type as the returned instance

Comment: @user1624552 If so then the only change I'd introduce to Kevin's sample code is that I would not have Y to have a where clause. I think that would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is this...

```
public interface IDataTypeConverterBase
{}

public interface IDataTypeConverter : IDataTypeConverterBase
{}

public interface IDataTypeConverter2 : IDataTypeConverterBase
{}

public static Y Convert<T, Y>(T itemToConvert)
    where T : IDataTypeConverterBase, new()
    where Y : IDataTypeConverterBase, new()
{
}
```

Comment: I think he wants something more powerful which says.  The type of the instance to be converted cannot be the same as the type of the returned instance.

Comment: But if not, this solution works well!

Comment: As steaks says, the type of the instance to be converted is not the same type as the returned instance.

Answer (score 0):

No, there can be only one *where* clause for each type parameter. 
[20.7 Constraints](http://edc.tversu.ru/elib/inf/0022/ch20lev1sec7.html)